# Rest method, link with what we return

Tags: rest, restful-url

I've read all best practices about Restfull API but they always use simple examples. I often read things like :

```
GET  /cars      -> return all cars
PUT  /cars/1    -> update car with id 1
etc...
```

So ok, we name the rest method "cars" because we're dealing with car resources.
But what about "advanced operations" ?

For example, I have a system where users have accounts. I want to create a GET method that allows to check if a person is linked to an account existing in database.

So I can create :

```
GET  /users/1/10   ->  return users data if user with id 1 is linked to the account with id 10
```

Is it good to name "/users" my method ? Knowing that the purpose to my method is not really to get user data but check if his account exists in databse

In other words, do we have to name our Rest methods depending on the data we return or depending on the purpose of the method ?

Answer (score 0):

1. if one user has more than one account and if you use two collections for users and accounts then route should be as follows to access a specific resource.

/users/{userId}/accounts/{accountID}.

You always need to maintain the relationship between resources. In this case, an account is a sub-resource of a user.

2. Or you can use filtering as follows

/users/{userId}/accounts?accountId=10

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you talk about maintaining relationship between resources, do I have to reproduce the exact structure between them ? For example, if you have a simple model where companies are linked to employees. Ok you say "/companies/1/employees/3" in order to get Employee 3 from company 1. But in some cases, structure is much more complex with a lot of tables linked. The url has to represent this complex structure ?

Comment: It is better if you can provide relationships with your resource URL up to a maximum of 2 subresources. If you have more complex relationships you don't need to do so due to the complexity. In that case, you can keep separate resource URL with filtering. Eg: GET all URL with filters :  /users?userId=1&accountId=10